# Update selected value in dropdown list depending on other lists selected values

Tags: javascript, dropdown

i'm trying to figure out how can i make dynamic selection of values in few dropdown lists using Vanilla JS. I have 3 dropdown lists with same values. Each of them should have different value selected at the same time (duplicates not allowed). So once user changes another value in one list, value of another list should be updated accordingly. Basically, i need to swap their numbers in such case. But i can't complete the task as I'm quite new to JS and overall in programming. I tried following:

```js
// defining initial values
var startPoint = document.querySelectorAll("select");

// function to recalculate value of each list on change
function calculateNewValues() {
  var changes = new Array();
  // getting updated values from lists as an array
  var updatedValues = document.querySelectorAll("select");
  // looping through array
  for (let i = 0; i < updatedValues.length; i++) {
    // if in updated array value of current index isn't equal to value
    // of index in initial array
    if (updatedValues[i].value != startPoint[i].value) {
      // creating variable changes for tracking
      changes[i] = updatedValues[i].value;
    }
    // if var changes has been defined (i.e. value of any list was updated)
    if (changes.length > 0) {
      // finding index of initial array with same value
      var key = startPoint.findIndex(changes[i]);
      // setting value of found index to previously stored value in updated list
      updatedValues[key].value = startPoint[i].value;
    }
  }

  updatedValues.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element.value);
  });
}
// event listeners for change of every dropdown list
const lists = document.querySelectorAll("select");
for (k = 0; k < lists.length; k++) {
  lists[k].addEventListener("change", calculateNewValues, false);
}
```

```html
<p>
  <select name="list1" id="list1">
    <option value="1" id="list1option1" selected>1</option>
    <option value="2" id="list1option2">2</option>
    <option value="3" id="list1option3">3</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>
  <select name="list2" id="list2">
    <option value="1" id="list2option1">1</option>
    <option value="2" id="list2option2" selected>2</option>
    <option value="3" id="list2option3">3</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>
  <select name="list3" id="list3">
    <option value="1" id="list3option1">1</option>
    <option value="2" id="list3option2">2</option>
    <option value="3" id="list3option3" selected>3</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

i am probably doing some mistake when it comes to `if (changes.length > 0) {`
but i can't understand how i can make this part better.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have assigned `startPoint` to querySelectorAll. Which will hold exact same objects whenever you write same querySelectorAll. So in your case `startPoint` and `updatedValues` will always same.

1. I have definen `startPoint` as an array of values and set its values in `setStartingPointValues()`.
2. Added `target` as current list which is being updated.
3. Updated `if (target.id == updatedValues[i].id && updatedValues[i].value != startPoint[i])` and retrieved `target`'s old value.
4. `var key = startPoint.findIndex(x => x == target.value);` will find select with value similar to new value. If we found key != -1, then update that select with oldValue.
5. Call `setStartingPointValues()` at end of change event.

```js
// defining initial values
var startPoint = [];

// store values for all select.
function setStartingPointValues() {
  startPoint = [];
  document.querySelectorAll("select").forEach(x => startPoint.push(x.value));
}

setStartingPointValues();

// function to recalculate value of each list on change
function calculateNewValues() {
  let target = this;
  let oldValue = 0;
  // getting updated values from lists as an array
  var updatedValues = document.querySelectorAll("select");
  // looping through array
  for (let i = 0; i < updatedValues.length; i++) {
    // if in updated array value of current index isn't equal to value    
    // of index in initial array    
    if (target.id == updatedValues[i].id && updatedValues[i].value != startPoint[i]) {
      // creating variable changes for tracking
      // changes[i] = updatedValues[i].value;
      oldValue = startPoint[i];
    }
    // if var changes has been defined (i.e. value of any list was updated)

    // finding index of initial array with same value
    var key = startPoint.findIndex(x => x == target.value);
    // setting value of found index to previously stored value in updated list
    if (key !== -1)
      updatedValues[key].value = oldValue;

  }

  setStartingPointValues();
}
// event listeners for change of every dropdown list
const lists = document.querySelectorAll("select");
for (k = 0; k < lists.length; k++) {
  lists[k].addEventListener("change", calculateNewValues, false);
}
```

```html
<p>
  <select name="list1" id="list1">
    <option value="1" id="list1option1" selected>1</option>
    <option value="2" id="list1option2">2</option>
    <option value="3" id="list1option3">3</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>
  <select name="list2" id="list2">
    <option value="1" id="list2option1">1</option>
    <option value="2" id="list2option2" selected>2</option>
    <option value="3" id="list2option3">3</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>
  <select name="list3" id="list3">
    <option value="1" id="list3option1">1</option>
    <option value="2" id="list3option2">2</option>
    <option value="3" id="list3option3" selected>3</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define good structure (store selected value somewhere) and rest should be easy

```js
const lists = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#list")).map(element => {
  const options = Array.from(element.children);
  const selected = options.findIndex(child => child.selected) + 1;
  
  return {
    element,
    options,
    selected
  }
  
});

const calculateNewValues = ({target}) => {
  const value = Number(target.value);
  
  const currentList = lists.find(pr => pr.element === target);
  const list = lists.find(pr => pr.selected === value)
  const oldValue = currentList.selected;
  currentList.selected = value;

  list.options[value - 1].selected = false;
  list.options[oldValue - 1].selected = true;
  list.selected = oldValue;
  
}

for(let {element} of lists) {
  element.addEventListener("change", calculateNewValues, false);
}
```

```html
<p>
    <select name="list1" id="list">
      <option value="1" selected>1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p>
    <select name="list2" id="list">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2" selected>2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p>
    <select name="list3" id="list">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3" selected>3</option>
    </select>
</p>
```